# What is a "lane ID" in Metal?

Tags: gpu, gpgpu, metal

I'm trying to understand SIMD-groups in Metal, and I'm hung up on what a "lane ID" is as there seems to be some conflicting documentation.

In Apple's example here: https://developer.apple.com/documentation/metal/creating_threads_and_threadgroups

It says that:

> [[simdgroup_index_in_threadgroup]]
>
> The unique scalar index of a SIMD group in its threadgroup, also known
>   as the lane ID.
>
> [[thread_index_in_simdgroup]]
>
> The unique scalar index of a thread in its SIMD group.

While in Apple's Metal Shading Language Specification document: https://developer.apple.com/metal/Metal-Shading-Language-Specification.pdf

In section 6.8.2, page 133, they give an example for `simd_shuffle_down` where it appears that the lane ID corresponds to `[[thread_index_in_simdgroup]]` which seems correct to me.

I think that the lane ID should instead be listed under `[[thread_index_in_simdgroup]]`, as the lane ID should be the index of the threads in the respective SIMD-group/Warp/Wavefront.

Is this correct?

Comment: Have you found the answer? I can't understand the example you mention so I'm searching for definitions.